# PHP PDO strange behavior: getting empty strings in result array ~ 1 out of 10 times

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

like 1 out of 10 times MySQL -> PDO replies with the right number of array elements but with them being all empty.
the other ~9 times i get the correct result on the same query.

(the PHP version i am forced to use is 5.3.1, MySQL version is 5.1.41)

my php function:

```
function getClientsByLike($dbh, $term)
{   

    $k=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT code, text FROM my_table WHERE text LIKE :search_term
        ORDER BY text ASC
        LIMIT 500
    ");

    $k->bindParam(":search_term", $x = "%".$term."%");
    $k->execute();

    while($obj = $k->fetch())
    {
        $result.= $obj['code'].' '.$obj['text'].'<br />';
    }

    return $result;
}


$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db', 'my_user', 'my_password', 
    array( 
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING,
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8',
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC
    )
);

echo getClientsByLike($dbh, "term");
```

the times it is working i get something like this as a result:

```
434 textblabla<br />
23 moretext<br />
95 evenmoretext<br />
```

when it's not working i get the correct amount of results, but all the returned strings are empty:

```
 <br />
 <br />
 <br />
```

sometimes the behavior is alternating with every execution of the script: working, not working, working, not working, and so on.

i've been working quite a bit now with PDO (like 3 months) but this is the first time i ran into a strange behavior like this.

any suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: Make PDOException to find out the issue.

Comment: thanks, but my code isn't producing any errors or warnings. i guess otherwise i wouldn't receive a resultset in the correct size but with no content.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

after further debugging my script with this method:

```
$clients = $k->fetchAll();

ob_start();
var_dump($clients);
$debug = ob_get_clean();

file_put_contents("result.txt", $debug."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

notice: i switched to `fetchAll()` now

i have found the reason for the strange behavior but still not exactly why this behavior occurs...

i took a look at the logfile i created for the result-arrays PDO returns:

result-array which works for me:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["code"]=>
    string(5) "31081"
    ["text"]=>
    string(28) "some text here"
  }
}
```

result-array which produced the strange behavior:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["my_table.code"]=>
    string(5) "31081"
    ["my_table.text"]=>
    string(28) "some text here"
  }
}
```

so suddenly PDO replies with `"table_name"."field_name"` instead of just `"field_name"` as expected. i don't change any PDO settings anywhere, they stay the same all the time.
the behavior of PDO - sometimes replying with the table name, sometimes without - seems quite random and like a serious bug to me (at least in PHP 5.3.1)

explicitly setting PDO to never fetch table names (in this script) should fix this for me:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_FETCH_TABLE_NAMES, false);
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what error you are getting. Maybe try wrap your prepare and execute method with PDOException might know the reason.

```
try{ 
$k=$dbh->prepare("
        SELECT code, text FROM my_table WHERE text LIKE :search_term
        ORDER BY text ASC
        LIMIT 500
    ");

    $k->bindParam(":search_term", $x = "%".$term."%");
    $k->execute();
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "<p style='color:red;'>{$e->getMessage()}</p>";
}
```

Comment: First, hes PDO won't throw exceptions and so there is nothing to catch. Second, one should never do such things like echo error messages.

Comment: Of course you should echo errors while in development!

Comment: what's the point in echoing errors manually while in development?

Comment: thanks, but my code isn't producing any errors or warnings.
i guess otherwise i wouldn't receive a resultset in the correct size but with no content.